# Why can the characteristic polynomial be used to find eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why is it that the characteristic polynomial for a matrix $A$

$$\phi(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$$

when finding the roots gives the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: because $A x = 0$ has non trivial solutions iff $det(A) = 0$

Comment: but why would you want $Ax = 0$? Shouldn't $Av = \lambda v$?

Comment: Yes, but apply the fact @vnd mentioned to $A-\lambda I$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By definition, an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ is a number $\lambda$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ where $x$ is a non zero vector, called the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. This means $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for this $x$. That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $A-\lambda I$ is not invertible. That is, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$. Here   $\det (A-\lambda I)$ is a polynomial in $\lambda$ and any $\lambda$'s satisfying this polynomial are  eigenvalues!

Comment: Why is it that $A - \lambda I$ must not be invertible?

Comment: Since, $(A-\lambda I)x=0$  means  there is a non zero vector $x$ in the null space of $A-\lambda I$, concluding $A-\lambda I$ is not one-one and hence not invertible

Answer (score 3):

$\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ iff $A-\lambda I$ has a non-trivial null space, which is true iff $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$, which is equivalent to $p(\lambda)=0$, where $p$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

We need a non zero vector $V$ to satisfy $$AV=\lambda V$$

Thus the homogeneous system $$(A-\lambda I)V=0$$ must have a nontrivial solution.

Thus we have to have $$det(A-\lambda I)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to find all $\lambda $ satisfuing $Ax= \lambda x \rightarrow (\lambda x -Ax)=0   \rightarrow(\lambda I -A)x=0 ; x \neq 0$ Therefore $ \lambda I -A$ is singular, meaning has determinant $0$ .
Expanding on the determinant, we find all $\lambda$ that satisfy this condition. Was this clear/helpful?

Comment: This is not clear, because $x$ is being used without being introduced, in particular without any quantifier.

Comment: @CarstenS $x$ is "quantified" by "$x \ne 0$" which applies to the whole chain of inferences.

Comment: @alephzero, does that mean "for all $x\ne0$", "for some $x\ne0$", "for my favorite $x\ne0$"? Also note that $\lambda$ has a quantifier, and the order matters. This kind of sloppiness is harmful when communicating with a beginner. Also note that "therefore" usually denotes implication in only one direction, which is less than what is wanted here.

Comment: @CarstenS: I dont see the need to quantify for $x \neq 0$ We want to find a solution to $Ax = \lambda x =0 $ for $ x \neq 0$. Just what else needs to be quantified? How is that sloppy? Where is the ambiguity?